# symfony: routing goes always on the same route

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, url-routing

I've got a big problem with routing: all pages matches with the same route!!

routing.yml

```
# default rules
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: home, action: index }

# generic rules
# please, remove them by adding more specific rules

localized_homepage:
  url:   /:sf_culture/
  param: { module: home, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)

change_language:
  url:   /change_language
  param: { module: language, action: changeLanguage }

contatti:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:contatti.html
  param: { module: contatti, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)

about:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:about.html
  param: { module: about, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)

opera_slug:
  url:   /:sf_culture/opere/:operaslug.html
  class:    sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: opera, action: permalink }
  options:  { model: Opera, type: object }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)

opere:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:opere.html
  param: { module: opera, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)


default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

_header.php

```
<ul>
<li><?php echo link_to(__('Home'), '@homepage') ?></li>
<li><?php echo link_to(__('About'), '@about?about='.strtolower(__('About'))) ?></li>
<li><?php echo link_to(__('Works'), '@opere?opere='.strtolower(__('Works'))) ?></li>
<li><?php echo link_to(__('Contacts'), '@contatti?contatti='.strtolower(__('Contacts'))) ?></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a button on my menu (_header), I'm always redirected to contacts page, and watching log, I can see

```
Match route "contatti" (/:sf_culture/:contatti.html) for /es/obras.html with parameters array ( 'module' => 'contatti', 'action' => 'index', 'sf_culture' => 'es', 'contatti' => 'obras',)
```

how is it possible? I've used @route sintax, so I tell symfony to use a particular route, but this is ignored.

do you have any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony matches routes from top to bottom so the first route that symfony finds a match for gets executed.

Your route is correctly expanded in your template but when the request is made symfony matches `/es/obras.html` correctly to the `@contatti` route. This happens because "obras" matches the ":contatti" parameter.

To solve your problem you need to give symfony a way to uniquely match your urls.

Hope this makes more sense to you now.

**Edit (unique routes):**

```
contatti:
  url:   /:sf_culture/contact/:contatti.html
  param: { module: contatti, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)

about:
  url:   /:sf_culture/about/:about.html
  param: { module: about, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)
```

Comment: yes, I know that symfony matches routes from top to bottom, but I thought that telling explicitly the name of the route then the system will use that one... do you have some hints to make these routes unique? thanks a lot

Comment: ok, perfect, thanks. now with your edit I've understood your hint... so this isn't any possibility to have urls like: www.webisite.com/about.html and www.website.com/contatti.html ?